# blank fields getting submitted on struts2 action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

1. The arraylist variable name is itmLst in action.
2. Item PurchaseDate,EntryDate,ItemCost and ItemDepreciation fields are to be displayed and accepted from user and to be submitted to action.

```jsp
<s:iterator value = "itmLst" status="row_id" var="itmLst" id="itmLst" >
    <s:if test="#row_id.index % 2 == 0">
        <tr class="yellow-bg"> 
    </s:if> 
    <s:else> 
        <tr class="gray-bg">
    </s:else>
    <td  class="label-left">
         <s:property value="itemNo" />
         <s:text name=":" />
         <s:property value="itemName" />
    </td>
    <td class="label-left"> 
       <s:textfield name = "itmLst.purDmys" 
                   value = "%{itmLst[#row_id.index].purDmys}"      
                      id = "purDmys%{#row_id.count}"
                cssClass = "TCMask[##/##/####,dd/mm/yyyy] textfield-date-month"
               maxLength = "10" />
    </td>
    <s:if test='itmLst.entCod == "T" || itmLst.entCod == "t"'>
        <td class="label-left"> 
           <s:textfield name = "itmLst.entDmys" 
                       value = "%{itmLst[#row_id.index].entDmys}"  
                          id = "entDmys%{#row_id.count}" 
                    cssClass = "TCMask[##/##/####,dd/mm/yyyy] textfield-date-month" 
                   maxLength = "10" />
     </td>
     </s:if>   
     <s:else>  
         <td class="label-left"> 
            <s:text name="N/A" />
         </td>               
    </s:else>
    <td  class="label-left"> <s:property value="itemStatus" /> </td>
    <td class="label-left"> 
           <s:textfield name = "itmLst.itemCost" 
                          id = "itemCost%{#row_id.count}" 
                       value = "%{itmLst[#row_id.index].itemCost}" 
                    cssClass = "textfield-amount" 
                   maxLength = "10" />
    </td>
    <td class="label-left"> 
         <s:textfield name = "itmLst.itemDepr" 
                        id = "itemDepr%{#row_id.count}" 
                     value = "%{itmLst[#row_id.index].itemDepr}" 
                  cssClass = "textfield-amount" 
                 maxLength = "10" />
     </td>
    <td  class="label-left"> <s:property value="depDmys" /> </td>
    <td  class="label-left"> <s:property value="sgDepAmt" /> </td>
    <td  class="label-left"> 
         <s:select name = "itmLst.actionSel" 
                   list = "#{ 'K':getText('Keep As It Is'),'M':getText('Update Modified Values') ,'D':getText('Delete Item') }" 
                  theme = "simple" />
    </td>
</tr>
    <s:if test="#row_id.index % 10 == 0">
        <tr align="center" >
            <td colspan="9">
                <s:submit key = "update" 
                     cssClass = "ovalbutton" 
                       method = "postItems" />

                <s:submit key = "cancel" 
                     cssClass = "ovalbutton" 
                           id = "cancelBtn" 
                       method = "cancel"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 1):

When submitted from JSP to action class, the list will always be blank unless you have named the elements on JSP like `itmList[0].itemNo`, `itmList[0].purDmys` etc.
You can assign these names while iterating the list.

Comment: checking your solution. will revert back later.

Comment: made changes as guided by you. Result is not encouraging. now the whole arraylist is gone. bean.itmLst.size is zero.

Comment: When you are iterating the list, you need to give the name attribute to different fields. E.g. <s:property name=%{list[index].itmName} etc

Comment: Do one thing. Write the name attribute in all the "S:" fields with the same string as value attribute.

Comment: solution did not work. s:property does not have a valid attribute name. it is accepted as valid for textfield. netbeans shows some TLD error if we add a name attribute for property field. arraylist size still becoming zero after modifying name tag as guided.

Comment: @user3422302 Solution works. Always put index in `name` attribute; always add an s:hidden field to the s:property fields you need to send back. ALWAYS INDENT CODE ;)

Comment: i have done as guided. kindly show your code for one single variable. i think one or two lines of code will be enough to make me understand what you want me to do.

Comment: Where is the hidden field. You have not inserted any hidden field in the modified code displayed above. I do not know the correct syntax to  insert hidden arraylist field in jsp. please modify the code above.

Comment: Solution Worked. No hidden field was required as data was already stored in session bean. Indenting is one of the best programming practices, thanks for reminding. Thanks to all of you.